# What do you call an armor plate that only covers the belly?

Tags: word-request

[image: Woman wearing armour]

What do you call an armor plate that only covers the belly? I wouldn't call it a breast plate, because the part covering the breast is separated from the part that covers the belly, so I was wondering if such a piece of armor that only covers the belly has a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the "[Plackart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plackart)"

[image: Suit of armour with labelled items]

Copyright @ 2005-2012 S.L. Kellaway, MedievalLifestyle.com

Note, this is a specialised term. It is not is common use. It is only likely to be known by people with an interest in suits of armour. Also note, that the image of the young woman in armour would not be like actual armour in use in the Medieval period, armour with lots of gaps in it would not be much protection.

Answer (score 1):

Note that while "plackart" is possibly correct, the armor as depicted in your picture is unrealistic.  Terms like this frequently apply only to the pieces that make up full suits of plate armor, and not this kind of haphazard protection.

First of all, why introduce a space between the breast plating and the belly plating, right where a blade might penetrate to the most vital organs?  Second, how the heck it it held on?  Does it tie in the back like a corset?  How does she keep it from slipping down?  Why not just make it all one piece with the rest of the armor covering the torso?

Fantasy armor is fantasy armor, and the various pieces don't always map to real-world examples.  No real-world armor ever had things like spiky shoulder pads, because these add extra weight for less protection.  No real-world armor left the thighs and groin uncovered, because even a small cut there could cause fatal bleeding.  And so on.

You might find this interesting:  [Firedryk Steel In-Stock Armor](http://firedryksteel.com/in_stock_armour).  Armorers like these guys make real armor for medieval recreation combat, so while the steel is probably far better than anything a medieval knight could hope to own, the armor is reasonably authentic, fully functional, and properly named.